# Using a function in a where clause that includes null search

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have a prepared statement in Java which uses the following SQL statement in the WHERE clause of my query, but I would like to re-write this into a function to limit the user parameters passed to it and possibly make it more efficient.

```
(
  (USER_PARAM2 IS NULL AND 
    ( COLUMN_NAME = nvl(USER_PARAM1, COLUMN_NAME) OR 
      (nvl(USER_PARAM1, COLUMN_NAME) IS NULL)
    )
  ) 
  OR 
  (USER_PARAM2 IS NOT NULL AND COLUMN_NAME IS NULL)
)
```

USER_PARAM1 and USER_PARAM2 are passed into the prepared statement by the user.
USER_PARAM1 represents what the application user wants to search this particular COLUMN_NAME for. If the user does not include this parameter, it will default to NULL.
USER_PARAM2 was my way to allow a user to request a NULL value only search on this COLUMN_NAME. Additionally I have some server logic that sets USER_PARAM2 to 'true' if passed in by the user or NULL if it wasn't specified by the user.

The intended behavior is that if USER_PARAM2 was declared then only COLUMN_NAME values of NULL are returned. If USER_PARAM2 wasn't declared and USER_PARAM1 was declared then only COLUMN_NAME = USER_PARAM1 are returned. If neither user params are declared then all rows are returned.

Could anyone help me out on this?
Thanks in advance...

EDIT:
Just to clarify this is how my current query looks (without the other WHERE clause statements..)

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE (
  (USER_PARAM2 IS NULL AND 
    ( COLUMN_NAME = nvl(USER_PARAM1, COLUMN_NAME) OR 
      (nvl(USER_PARAM1, COLUMN_NAME) IS NULL)
    )
  ) 
  OR 
  (USER_PARAM2 IS NOT NULL AND COLUMN_NAME IS NULL)
)
```

... and this is where I would like to get to...

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE customSearchFunction(USER_PARAM1, USER_PARAM2, COLUMN_NAME)
```

EDIT #2:
OK, so another co-worker helped me out with this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function searchNumber (pVal IN NUMBER, onlySearchForNull IN CHAR, column_value IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  IF onlySearchForNull IS NULL THEN 
    IF pVal IS NULL THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      IF pVal = column_value THEN
        RETURN 1;
      ELSE
        RETURN 0;
      END IF;  
    END IF;  
  ELSE 
    IF column_value IS NULL THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;  
  END IF;
END;
```

... this seems to work in my initial trials..

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE 1=searchNumber(USER_PARAM1, USER_PARAM2, COLUMN_NAME);
```

... the only issues I have with it would be 
1)possible performance concerns vs the complex SQL statement I started with.
2)that I would have to create similar functions for each data type. 
However, the latter would be less of an issue for me.

EDIT #3 2012.02.01

So we ended up going with the solution I chose below, while using the function based approach where code/query cleanliness trumps performance. We found that the function based approach performed roughly 6x worse than using pure SQL.

Thanks everyone for the great input everyone!

EDIT #4 2012.02.14

So looking back I noticed that applying the virtual table concept in @Alan's solution with the clarity of @danihp's solution gives a very nice overall solution in terms of clarity and performance. Here's what I now have

```
WITH   params AS (SELECT user_param1 AS param, user_param2 AS param_nullsOnly FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
FROM   table_name, params p
WHERE  ( nvl(p.param_nullsOnly, p.param) IS NULL                  --1)
         OR p.param_nullsOnly IS NOT NULL AND column_name IS NULL --2)
         OR p.param IS NOT NULL AND column_name = p.param         --3)
       )
-- 1) Test if all rows should be returned
-- 2) Test if only NULL values should be returned
-- 3) Test if param equals the column value
```

Thanks again for the suggestions and comments!

Comment: Why change to a function? Native SQL, although possibly messy looking, will certainly perform better.

Comment: If you really want a function, then your "customSearchFunction" must return a varchar2 value (eg S/N). And your where will be WHERE customSearchFunction(USER_PARAM1, USER_PARAM2, COLUMN_NAME) = 'S'

Comment: Using a function as you've stated is likely to force a full table scan when evaluating your statement. If it's a small table (or a join of small tables) this may not matter, but if it's a large table the performance may leave much to be desired. YMMV.

Comment: @SergioMichels - thanks for helping me recognize my English-centricity.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the responses!
The reason I was thinking of a function was that
1) I am using this query in a prepared statement from a java web application, and am trying to reduce the amount of redundant parameters passed into the query.
2) I was told by a co-worker that a function (something like nvl()) might be better performance than the 2 branched statement my ORs created. I am not that knowledgeable in Oracle or SQL performance tuning, so I took his advice.

Comment: @SérgioMichels The only issue I have with that is the complexity of this statement is derived from the inclusion of NULL values in the COLUMN. My statements for COLUMN that don't require NULLS is actually much smaller and don't need the USER_PARAM2.
e.g. 
WHERE customSearchFunction(USER_PARAM1, USER_PARAM2, COLUMN_NAME) = 'S'
would not return any records with NULL values since NULL != NULL (at least in Oracle)

Comment: @hypno7oad that depends how your function will handle the null values. You can have null values and still return 'S'...

Comment: The Oracle function must return a value, either char or numeric. So you need customSearchFunction(...) = 'Y', or customSearchFunction(...) = 1, etc...

Comment: @SérgioMichels Thanks. You're response helped my co-worker and I craft the function I included above.

Comment: @hypno7oad glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple way of to pass your parameters only once and refer to them as many times as needed, using common-table expressions:

```
WITH params AS (SELECT user_param1 AS up1, user_param2 AS up2 FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
FROM   table_name, params p
WHERE  ((p.up2 IS NULL 
         AND (column_name = NVL(p.up1, column_name) 
              OR (NVL(p.up1, column_name) IS NULL)))
        OR (p.up2 IS NOT NULL AND column_name IS NULL))
```

In effect, you're creating a virtual table, where the columns are your parameters, that is populated with a single row.

Conveniently, this also ensures that all of your parameters are collected in the same place and can be specified in an arbitrary order (as opposed to the order that the naturally appear in the query).

There are a couple big advantages to this over a function-based approach. First, this will not prevent the use of indexes (as pointed out by @Bob Jarvis). Second, this keeps the query's logic in the query, rather than hidden in functions.

Comment: Thanks for this! I really like this approach for the combination of speed and eliminating redundant parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if my approach has more performance, but it has best readability:

Sending 2 additionals parameters to query you can rewrite query like:

```
where
( P_ALL_RESULTS is not null
  OR
  P_ONLY_NULLS is not null AND COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
  OR
  P_USE_P1 is not null AND COLUMN_NAME = USER_PARAM1
)
```

**Disclaimer: answered before OP question clarification**

Comment: The last condition should read: P_USE_P1 is not null AND COLUMN_NAME = USER_PARAM1

Comment: disclaimer: answered before OP question clarification .

Comment: @BD. You're right

Thanks for the response, danihp. This might be the approach I go if I can't find an appropriate function based solution. The only reason I won't choose this now, is that I would like to reduce the amount of passed in USER_PARAMs to the least amount possible.